# Usage of aussteigen versus steigen + aus etwas (dative)

Tags: preposition, verb-usage

I am trying to understand which of the following two sentences is more appropriate to signify getting out of a car:

(1) *Ich steige aus dem Auto aus.*  (Usage of *aussteigen*)

(2) *Ich steige aus dem Auto.*  (Usage of *steigen* + *aus etwas* (dative) )

The only difference I can think of is that (1) refers to getting out of a car in the normal fashion – open the door and step out.  (2) Can refer also to climbing out – i.e through the window if need be.  Therefore *aussteigen* is the preferred option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ich steige aus dem Auto aus.
>
> Ich steige aus dem Auto.

None of these two is really *preferred* over the other. You are right *steigen* as the more general verb also covers climbing through the sunroof. But noone would assume that just by leaving out the final *aus*, because *steigen* is only used in a metaphorical sense here.

It does matter as soon there is some real climbing involved:

> Der Dieb stieg aus der Dachluke.

*The burglar climbed out of the skylight.*

> Der Dieb stieg aus der Dachluke aus.

*The burglar left the building through the skylight.*